# Unable to sync gradle in android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android

Error:Failed to open zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
(Re-download dependencies and sync project(Requires network)

Hello please help,
I am using android studio 3.0.1. I have active internet connection then also this problem arrive. I also did it manually i.e.in gradle folder i manuaaly added that distribution gradle-4.1-all.zip.
But it didn't worked!! please help.

Comment: delete cache folder from .gradle folder and try again.

Comment: delete .idea and .grade folder from your project and clean it ..It work :)

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project. Delete `.idea` and `.grade` folder from your project folder. Now build your project.

If still fails, try running `gradlew` from Terminal in Android Studio. Still fails, check your network connection and/or proxy settings.

Comment: No it didn't worked for me. Yes I have active internet connection.after running gradlew command result is build successful but the error remains same. I am facing this problem in "only" android studio 3.0.1. I have also checked in android-studio 2.2.3................Please help

Comment: I have used local gradle distribution and its done.But I have tried all the ways that u people told, may be that things helped to solved my issue. So thank you very much all of you.